# WordPress: Highlight search results - but keeping the same case as was originally on the page

Tags: php, wordpress, search, replace, preg-replace

For my WordPress Search results page, I have added highlighting to show where search term appears on the results page.  But the replacement code changes the text of the page to the **case** that was used in the search term.

For example:

```
Search Term:                                      remote Employee ENGAGE 
Text on Page before highlight:                    Remote employee engagement 
Resulting text after highlight replacement:       remote Employee ENGAGEment
Desired text after highlight replacement:         Remote employee engagement
```

Here is the code I used in my content-search.php

```
<?php $title = str_ireplace( $s, '<span class="search-instance">'.$s.'</span>', get_the_title() ) ?>
<?php $excerpt = str_ireplace( $s, '<span class="search-instance">'.$s.'</span>', get_the_excerpt() ) ?> 
<?php echo $title; ?>   
<?php echo $excerpt; ?>
```

And the css to highlight the text:

```
span.search-instance {
   font-weight: bold;
   background: #fffdca;
   padding: 2px;
}
```

Can someone offer some suggestions on how to get the highlighting done, with a case-insensitive search, but also without changing the case of the text on the page during the highlighting process.

Cheers,
SunnyOz

## **UPDATE:**

I don't think I can do what I want with `str_ireplace`.

I think I will probably need to use something like `preg_replace` with some `regex` that also **allows partial matches** (ie: Don't limit to match a word boundary)- but I don't know how to set that up in my code example.

If it is true that I need to use `preg_replace` instead of `str_ireplace`, I could still use some help.

How can you do a **case-insensitive** search of the `get_the_title()` and `get_the_excerpt()` separately with the search term used - using `preg_replace`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$string = 'Test test REmotE emPloYee engAgeMent end string ';
$keys = array('remote Employee ENGAGE');

$patterns = array();

foreach($keys as $key) {    
$patterns[] = '/\b('.$key.'([^ ]*))\b/i';
echo preg_replace($patterns, '<span class="search-instance">$0</span>', $string);
}
```

What was the problem with your code, you were looking for a phrase and making a substitution.
In this situation, we need to find a pattern in the string and if something matches this pattern then wrap that match with tags.

Comment: I was just going to answer my own question, when I saw your comment.  You are definitely on the right track, and may work for most people, so I accepted it as the answer.  But I will also include my own answer that specifically addresses my code.

Answer (score 1):

I did find a way to do what I wanted.  I found the solution from this page: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-highlight-the-search-terms-in-results-in-wordpress/

Here is the new code I changed:

```
<?php $title = get_the_title(); $keys= explode(" ",$s); $title = preg_replace('/('.implode('|', $keys) .')/iu', '<span class="search-instance">\0</span>', $title); ?>
<?php $excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); $keys= explode(" ",$s); $excerpt = preg_replace('/('.implode('|', $keys) .')/iu', '<span class="search-instance">\0</span>', $excerpt); ?>
```